# DataSource callback undefined when using JSONP

Tags: kendo-ui

Using KendoUI for the first time, playing with DataSource. Keep getting `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`. The service response comes back as expected, with the callback in there. Tried with and without specifying the callback function name, same problem. The "change" function is never, triggered, obviously.

The code couldn't be simpler:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "http://my-service-domain/hotels.jsonp?city=Denver",
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                        jsonpCallback: "myCallBack",
                    }
                },
                change: function(e){
                    console.log(e);
                }
            });

// read data from the remote service
dataSource.read();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it `jsonpCallback` or `jsonpCallbackString`? Check: http://www.telerik.com/forums/datasource-jsonp-random-callback-function-name

> The Kendo UI DataSource relies entirely on $.ajax for making remote
>   service requests. The jsonpCallbackString setting can be used to set
>   your own callback name. Here is how to do this via the transport:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({    
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "....",
            jsonpCallbackString: "mycallback"
       }
    }
});
```